# Smooth functions of compact support and continuous functions on the closure

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, continuity

Let $G\subseteq \mathbb{R}^N$ be an open set. I want to show that $C_0^\infty (G) \subseteq C(\bar{G})$, where $C_0^\infty (G)$ represents the smooth functions with compact support on $G$, and $C(\bar{G})$ represents the continuous functions on $\bar{G}$.

My idea is to consider a function $f \in C_0^\infty (G)$, and using the compact support of $f$, show that for all $A \subseteq \bar{G}$, $f(\bar{A}) \subseteq \bar{f(A)}$.

Comment: If $f\in C^\infty_0(G)$ then $f\in C^\infty(\mathbb R^n)$.

Comment: Why $C_0^\infty (G) \subseteq C^\infty(\mathbb{R}^n)$. A function $f$ could not have derivative of some order in some point outside $G$ although it is smooth and have compact support on G. For example, consider $G=(0,1)$, and $f(x)=0$ if $x \in G$, $f(x)=x$ if $x \in \mathbb{R}\setminus G$.

Comment: Here it is meant that $f$ is extended by zero outside $G$.